# How to get all of the content from rss URL

Tags: php, database, rss, wordpress

I'm working on a automated system in which a cron job automatically get the fresh content from  a RSS feed , then store them to Database for later use... (May be used as WP post)...

All is working good, but only problem is I got only small description. I want to pull the full post content from the rss feed? not just the excerpt.

**Im Using WordPress Not Codeigniter**

PHP Code used by me

RSSLink = http://feeds.feedburner.com/learnhack

```
 $rss = fetch_feed($entry->rss_link);
   foreach ($rss->get_items() as $item)
    {
        var_dump($item);
        $page_content = array(
            'post_title' => $item->get_title(),
            'post_content' => $item->get_description(),
            );
        // Data base insert statements
     }
```

OutPut :

SimplePie_Item Object ( [feed] => SimplePie Object ( [data] => Array ( [child] => Array     ( [] => Array ( [rss] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => [attribs] => Array ( [] => Array ( [version] => 2.0 ) ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => [child] => Array ( [] => Array ( [channel] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => [child] => Array ( [] => Array ( [title] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => Learn The Basics Of Ethical Hacking [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) [link] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => http://www.basicsofhacking.com/ [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) [description] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => Learn About Ethical Hacking Techniques: What Is Hacking, Email Hacking, System Hacking, Website Hacking, Facebook Hacking, Google Hacking etc. [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) [language] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => en [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) [managingEditor] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => noreply@blogger.com (Harwinder Kumar) [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) [lastBuildDate] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => Sun, 24 Nov 2013 08:25:03 PST [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) [generator] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => Blogger http://www.blogger.com [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) [image] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => [child] => Array ( [] => Array ( [link] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/ [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) [url] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => http://creativecommons.org/images/public/somerights20.gif [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) [title] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => Some Rights Reserved [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) ) ) ) ) [item] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => [child] => Array ( [] => Array ( [title] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => WordPress Security: Securing Sites From Hackers / Future Attacks [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) [link] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/learnhack/~3/nSMFsPWxWQQ/wordpress-security-securing-sites-from-hackers.html [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) [category] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => BASICS OF ETHICAL HACKING [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) [1] => Array ( [data] => WORDPRESS TRICKS [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) [author] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => noreply@blogger.com (Harwinder Kumar) [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) [pubDate] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => Wed, 30 Oct 2013 09:59:56 PDT [attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) [guid] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-8198217290464183069.post-3028513166465596533 [attribs] => Array ( [] => Array ( [isPermaLink] => false ) ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] =>      [xml_lang] => ) ) [description] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => As WordPress is the most popular CMS available on the web but also vulnerable to threats if we don't follow the necessary security measures. In one of previous guest post, Sarah Rexman mentioned some tips about securing WordPress and in this post I'm gonna share my own experience. While working as freelancer on oDesk, Elance and Freelancer; clients always have issues about securing their sites from hackers and ask about how to prevent from...

[attribs] => Array ( ) [xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) ) [http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/] => Array ( [thumbnail] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => [attribs] => Array ( [] => Array ( [url] => http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-meTNpj8B758/UOR5j1OmE5I/AAAAAAAAAvk/UtCMCLa_C3Q/s72-c/WordPress+Security.jpg [height] => 72 [width] => 72 ) )

Also I want to store the RSS post images on my server, no hotlinking

Comment: How about you use var_dump($item) and see what data is in there, based on that you may pull whatever you wish

Comment: Ya I tried the same , and get the content only in get_description

Comment: need more details, what are you getting from RSS feed

Comment: `fetch_feed()` is codeigniter, so added the tag.

Comment: need more details,either the rss url, or the output of $item, if only small description is available in rss, then you wont get other things which you want.

Comment: @IrfanDANISH I updated the post with related info

Comment: @Jack Im using WordPress not Codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

The description of an RSS feed contains only what the author decides to put in there. This may be a full article, but it may also just be a summary of something.

If you need the full article I think you're pretty much stuck with fetching whatever you get through the URL in the `link` element.

For image and other media files you'll probably have to parse the HTML, and download each element manually. Not to mention rewrite all the paths... good luck with that...

---

*Also, if scraping and copying someone elses blog into your own willy-nilly is what you're up to, then please just stop...*

Comment: I have my 5-6 blog of mine what i want to get all together in blog so i develop this plugin for me ...

Here is a site which get all the content trough RSS feed http://fulltextrssfeed.com/

Comment: If they are in fact *your* blogs, then why don't you just connect directly to the databases and pull the content from there? Or even better, just use the WordPress import/export tool, merge your content into one blog and throw away the others? Having 5-6 blogs when you can have one blog with 5-6 categories seems a bit of a hassle... especially if you want all the content on one blog either way...

Comment: I need them to auto sync ... and I used the different server for every blog

Comment: Well, I would still take a step back and see if you really need the content spread across so many blogs. Maintaining one blog is a lot simpler. And if the content is so different they need their own blogs, well, then there shouldn't be much reason for merging them back into a single one. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: my client want me to that .. and i cant say them no